# How to take input of index of array as tuple?

Tags: python

Here is my code. I cannot face how to take input of index of array as tuple? :

```
import numpy as np

def create_board():
    print(np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int))

player = int(input("Enter if the player is 1 or 2:      \n "))
position=tuple(input("Enter the desired position of your marker Example: (0,1)   \n "))
board=create_board()


def place(board, player, position):
    if player==1:
        board[position]= 1
    else :
        board[position]= 0
    return board


place(board, player, position)
```

Comment: Helloand welcome to SO : we will need more details on what you need to achieve ... what part of your code cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't bother.  Why should the user have to conform to Python language notation?  The parentheses and comma are mere syntactic sugar, the same for all inputs.  Instead, just get the values:

```
position = input("Enter the desired position as two integers: ").split()
```

Granted, there is no error-checking on this -- that's not part of your question.
With valid input, this gives you a list of two elements, ready to use.  If you *must* have a tuple, a simple casting does the job.

```
position = tuple(position)
```

Details are left as an exercise for the student.  :-)